# How can I merge two data frames with multiple common keys without duplicating rows in R?

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

For instance, say I want to merge df1 and df2 (see below). Not only do they have different #s of rows but also different #s of columns. They also have multiple columns that repeat themselves, as well as values under the "Sales" column that repeat themselves. What I'd like to do is merge by "Sales" (don't want duplicate values under "Sales") and by "Date", "Price", and "SKU" (duplicate values under these columns are OK), and adding in the "PVC" column and filling any missing cells w/ NA values. Basically, here's the end product I want:

```
Date        Sales Price SKU   PVC
2007/01/02   1     1.29 52648 Q
2007/01/02   2     1.99 48721 N/A
2007/01/02   5     0.55 65897 N/A
2007/01/02   6     5.00 56482 N/A
2007/01/02   10    2.50 46521 N/A
2009/01/02   4     5.99 75677  Z
```

Doing this with:

```
merge(df1,df2,c("Date","Sales","Price","SKU"),all=TRUE)
```

does not work, because it gets rid of any rows that don't completely match on all 4 of those columns. Trying:

```
merge(df1,df2,by="Sales",all=TRUE)
```

does not work, because that makes rows that share the same values under "Sales" repeat themselves. Also, I don't want to see columns like "Date", "Price", and "SKU" repeat themselves in the merged data frame (I wind up with "Date.x", "Date.y", "Price.x", "Price.y", "SKU.x", "SKU.y").

df1

```
Date        Sales Price SKU
2007/01/02   1     1.29 52648
2007/01/02   2     1.99 48721
2007/01/02   5     0.55 65897
2007/01/02   6     5.00 56482
2007/01/02   10    2.50 46521
```

df2

```
Date        Sales Price SKU   PVC
2007/01/02   1     3.29 52647  Q
2009/01/02   4     5.99 75677  Z
```

Comment: Can you please add one more dataset: Ideal Output dataset of `merge`. That is, what do you want the output of `merge()` to look like?

Comment: @Andrew Taylor, just added that to the top! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), Sales)
setkey(setDT(df2), Sales)

df1[df2, PVC := i.PVC]
rbind(df1, df2[!df1])

#          Date Sales Price   SKU PVC
# 1: 2007/01/02     1  1.29 52648   Q
# 2: 2007/01/02     2  1.99 48721  NA
# 3: 2007/01/02     5  0.55 65897  NA
# 4: 2007/01/02     6  5.00 56482  NA
# 5: 2007/01/02    10  2.50 46521  NA
# 6: 2009/01/02     4  5.99 75677   Z
```

- `setDT` converts *data.frames* to *data.tables* (without actually copying the data).
- `setkey()` *sorts* the data by `Sales` column on both *data.tables*, and marks those columns as *key columns*, which we'll use to join.
- In *data.tables*, joins are of the form `x[i]` where `x` is a *keyed data.table* and `i` may or may not be keyed. It performs the join by finding matching rows in `x` corresponding to each row in `i`.

  Therefore `df1[df2]` finds all matching rows in `df1` corresponding to each row in `df2`. The only one that matches is `Sales = 1`. And on that match, we assign a new column `PVC` to `df1`, whose value is from `df2`'s `PVC` column - denoted using `i.PVC` (to distinguish which data.table we refer to when both data.tables have the same column name).
- Lastly, we perform a *non-join* or *anti-join* to get all the rows in `df2` that are not in `df1` (once again matched by the key column `Sales`) and simply bind to get the final result.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Using `library(dplyr)`:

```
left_join(rbind(df1,df2[,-5]) %>% group_by(Sales) %>% slice(1), df2[,c(2,5)])
```

Here is an explanation, with commands broken out line by line.  Doing it like this, I used the library `magrittr` for its handy `%<>%` operator which is a combination of `<-` and `%>%`

```
df2_noPVC <- df2 %>% select(-PVC) ## pare down df2 so they can be row-bound
bound <- rbind(df1,df2_noPVC) ## stack the dataframes
bound %<>% group_by(Sales) %>% slice(1) ## take the first row for each sale #, removing duplicates
result <- left_join(bound,df2[,c(2,5)]) ## now that you have the unique records, merge back the PVC field
```

The twist comes from this being a combination of a `merge` and an `rbind`.  If you wanted the Sales = 1 record from `df2`, not `df1`, it would be a simpler problem, you could just `rbind` and `slice` (de-dupe) without the merge.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of `base::merge` and `dplyr`. Also definitely not the prettiest solution. I'd be interested in seeing someone give a better solution, as I'm certain there is one with only `merge` or a simple `dplyr` string of arguments.

```
df<- rbind(merge(df1,df2[,c(2,5)],by=c("Sales"),all.x=TRUE),df2) %>% 
  group_by(Sales) %>% 
  filter(row_number(desc(Sales)) == 1) %>% 
  arrange(Sales)



  Sales       Date Price   SKU PVC
1     1 2007/01/02  1.29 52648   Q
2     2 2007/01/02  1.99 48721  NA
3     4 2009/01/02  5.99 75677   Z
4     5 2007/01/02  0.55 65897  NA
5     6 2007/01/02  5.00 56482  NA
6    10 2007/01/02  2.50 46521  NA
```